# Scanner buffer is not clearing

Tags: java, input, while-loop

I write this block of code to run three times. And each time when user enter a non-integer value then the inner while breaks.

```
while(i<=2)
        {
            total=0;
            numOfint=0;
            while (true)
                {

                    System.out.print("Please enter an integer");
                    if(!in.hasNextInt())
                    {break;}
                    else
                    {
                    total+=in.nextInt();
                    numOfint+=1;
                    }
                }
            avg[i]=new Average();
            avg[i].numb_ints=numOfint;
            avg[i].total_ints=total;
            System.out.println("Stats for average "+i+". Number of ints : "+avg[i].numb_ints+" Total : "+avg[i].total_ints+" Average: "+avg[i].avg_ints());
            i++;
        }
```

The problem is it runs only 1 time. and second times it just skips the inner while loop. I think there is last non-integer value in scanner buffer which isn't clearing. Kindly help me in it.

Comment: The loop condition while (true) will be executed forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it once you entered a NAN it will break all the rest , there is no nextint in the buffer ,
try to next the scanner ,try this:

```
if(!in.hasNextInt()){
String tmp=in.next();
break;
}
```